# How do I style Silverlight chart marker?

Tags: charts, wpftoolkit, silverlight-toolkit, toolkit

I am using the Silverlight 4 Toolkit chart control (and also the WPF chart control).

My goal is to have a marker that is an arbitrary symbol - for example I need a marker style that is an X.

It can be an image, or a char, I don't mind.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Here is the style for an arbitrary squiggle.

(DVC is my xmlns for the Datavisualistion Charting toolkit).

In my Grid.Resources:

```
<Style x:Key="Squiggle" TargetType="DVC:ScatterDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate  TargetType="DVC:ScatterDataPoint">
                        <Canvas>
                            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                                Data="M 1,20 C 10,30 40,30 40,20 H 30" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The squiggle marker is just an example. You can draw any shape you like:
[Shapes and drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Then in the Chart.Series:

```
<DVC:ScatterSeries Title="Squiggles" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource Squiggle}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
            </DVC:ScatterSeries>
```